# How to handle exception thrown by struts2 when call actions by ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, exception, struts2

I use jquery post method to call `save` method in `DepartmentAction`, if I save a dup department(dup department is not allowed in db), the `save` method throws an Exception, but user can't get any information about it from the page, here is my code:

DepartmentAction class:

```
public class DepartmentAction extends ActionSupport{
  public String save() throws Exception
   {
    this.departmentService.save(this.dept);
    this.jsonResult = "success";
    return "save";
  }
 }
```

struts.xml:

```
<package name="backstage-default" extends="ecs-default" namespace="/manager">
   <action name="dept_*" class="com.nader.action.DepartmentAction" method="{1}">
      <result name="save" type="json"><param name="root">jsonResult</param></result>
   </action>

 <global-results>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error"         />
    </global-exception-mappings>
```

test.jsp:

```
     $.post('dept_save.do', 
                 {'dept.deptId':$("#dialog_dept_deptId").val(), 
                  'dept.deptName':$("#dialog_dept_deptName").val(),
                  'dept.manager':$("#dialog_dept_manager").val(),
                 },function(data, status, xhr){
                     alert(status);
                     if(status == 'success'){
                         alert('success:'+data);
                         $("#dialog-form").dialog("close");
                         getCountByAJAX();
                         getDeptByAJAX();
                     }else{
                         alert('error:'+data);
                     }
                  }
                 ,"json").fail(function(data, status, xhr)          {alert('fail:'+data);});
```

when `save` throws an Exception, user doesn't get any info, no errors, no redirecting, so what should I do? I don't want to write `try catch` block in Actions, because it is too much to make code messy. Are there some other ways?

Thanks in advance.

ps: I am really sorry, I just pasted the wrong `javascript` block, I correct it, now the `fail` handler was executed when struts2 throws an exception, but I don't know what the `data` passed to browser is, and I see the response of `dept_save.do` in chrome tools, it contains all exceptionStack info, that's too much, can struts returns some small info or friendly tip info?

Comment: Return a json response and use it to render a meaningful message, like a pop up or updated div.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to write try catch block in Actions, because it is too much to make code messy.

That is a nonsense argument. When components of the framework you are using might throw exceptions, than you *have* to catch those *if* you want to keep control of the programm flow and not have it just break on errors.

(You do of course not have to catch that exception there and than – exceptions can be caught at later points in the program flow as well. They just have to be caught at all somewhere before the program ends.)